# File upload on server

Tags: java, file-io, applet, japplet

I have created an applet which creates a file on running it. But when I run my applet via server, it fails.

Is there any possible way to create a file on server with applet?

EDIT:I am creating a sound record applet which works fine when I run the applet in browser locally.It actually creates a file of recorded sound,but when I run the same applet on server,it does not create file.Is it because the server does not allow you to do so?

Is there any possible solution so that the file can be created?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` objects always point to a location (that may not exist) on the client machine.

To store something on a server, it would require some server side functionality to accept the bytes and create a (server-side) `File`.  That might be done with PHP, servlets/JSP, ASP etc.  Once the server-side is organized to accept the bytes, the applet can connect to it and push the sound recording through.

Answer (score 1):

Java Applets are run on the client machine. Once you invoke the page containing an applet, the applet gets downloaded to the client's machine and runs. Hence it will not get access to the server.